# How can I parametize the intersection of sphere and plane?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am doing Stokes' theorem and have to parametize the the curve of intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and plane $x+y+z=0$

I can't think of any parametization..

I let $z=-y-x$ and plug in sphere equation and got nothing

Answer (score 1):

This curve will be a circle centered at the origin (why?).   Any circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at the origin admits a parametrization of the form $\alpha(t) = \mathbf{v_1}\cos(t) + \mathbf{v_2}\sin(t)$, where $\mathbf{v_1}$ and $\mathbf{v_2}$ are orthogonal vectors of equal magnitude.

One way of going about finding appropriate vectors $\mathbf{v_1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ would be to choose an arbitrary $\mathbf{v_1}$ on the boundary of the circle: say $x = 0, y=-a/\sqrt{2}$ and $z = a/\sqrt{2}$.  Then find the unit normal vector $N$ to the plane and take $\mathbf{v}_2 = N \times \mathbf{v}_1$.